# AppCompat Theme Error when using NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I'm using a toolbar for my entire application. So I have set up my application Theme to **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** But I need to show a alert dialog in a part of my app. When I try to show alert dialog I'm getting Runtime error about **Theme.Appcompat**

[image]

My manifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.project.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.project.StActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

What should i do
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code where you actually create the `Dialog`, but my guess is that you're either:

1. Not using the `Activity` as the `Context` when you create the `Dialog`. The `Activity` context holds the theme; if you tried using the `Application` it wouldn't get the right theme.
2. Setting your `Dialog` theme to something that doesn't inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` (using the constructor, `setStyle()` or `ContextThemeWrapper`).

Either way, the `Dialog` doesn't get the required attributes provided by `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: I've solved the problem with changing my context object to Activity context thanks =)